# How to convert str to int and add them together?

Tags: python, string, int, concatenation, addition

I've spent the last 2 hours trying to find a solution for this and came up with nothing. So either this is not possible or its so basic that no one write about this. Basically I have 2 strings that both equal numbers, but when I go to add them together I get a concatenate instead of a number.. here is my code (Python)

```
currentNukeScriptName = nuke.root().name()
splitUpScriptName1 = currentNukeScriptName.split('/')
splitUpScriptName2 = splitUpScriptName1[-1]
splitScriptNameAndExtention = splitUpScriptName2.split('.')
currentNukeScriptName = splitScriptNameAndExtention[0]
splitUpCurrentScriptName = currentNukeScriptName.split('_')
currentVersionNumber = splitUpCurrentScriptName[-1]
decimalVersionNumber =  "1" + "," + str(currentVersionNumber)
addingNumber = 1
newVersionNumber = str(decimalVersionNumber) + str(addingNumber)

print newVersionNumber

decimaleVersionNumber = 1,019
```

If I change the newVersionNumber code too:

```
newVersionNumber = int(decimalVersionNumber) + int(addingNumber)
```

I get:

```
# Result: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,019'
```

I am unsure what to do.. Is this not possible? Or am I doing something totally wrong?

Edit:

So the problem was found in the decimalVersionNumber where I was adding a comma. What would be the best way of keeping the comma and still adding the numbers together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,019'
```

Sounds like it doesn't like the comma - try removing it first.

Comment: I commented earlier and said it didn't work but I think I missed something because it works now :S. You are right.. so if I want to keep the comma what should I do?

Comment: Just remove it (programatically) before you parse the integer and you'll be fine. Unless you want to mess around with the `locale` module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
int.Parse(decimalVersionNumber) + int.Parse(addingNumber)
```

This will parse the string representation of the numbers into integers, so they can be added.

eg:

String concatenation:

"10" + "20" = "1020"

Integer addition, parsed from strings:

int.Parse("10") + int.Parse("20") = 30

Comment: I tried this but it tells me this:

    # Result: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
    AttributeError: type object 'int' has no attribute 'parse'

Comment: @user1159817: I think he thought you were writing in C#.

Comment: ah yes I could see why, I forgot to tag python when I first asked this question